# Intake Mechanism with Obstacle

Tags: mechanical-engineering, robotics

I'm not exactly sure if this is where I'm supposed to ask, but engineering stack exchange is the closest because my question is about robotics. I'm sorry if this doesn't fit.

> **Question:** Are there any intake mechanisms that are efficient and quick, but are designed to accommodate obstacles that are in the way?

Let me explain my question. Essentially, let's say you have a robot with an intake that's supposed to take in different sized objects like cubes and spheres. However, to get to the cubes and spheres, there's a three inch tall wall in the way.

The standard way of retrieving the objects is to go over the wall, which might be possible, but I'm asking if there's another way without going over the wall. I've thought about some sort of extension that goes over the wall, but it's risky if your actual intake is heavy.

Any thoughts? I've spent some time thinking about this and I'm still haven't come up with an idea.

Comment: I think there is a seperate robotics stack exchange.

Comment: How can an "extension that goes over the wall" be acceptable if you want another way **without** going over the wall?

Comment: @SolarMike I meant the robot physically rolls over the wall or breaks it down. Sorry if I wasn’t clear.